# Reflections disappear when rendering 4x size

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Thank you I will try cpu. Gtx 1050ti always crashes blender when trying branched path tracing, so used path tracing with gpu.

When rendering reflective surface (floor plane) at 1920 x 1080 cycles, path tracing it looks great. But most reflective details on floor disappear and go dull with same settings at 8000 x 4500 for printing. Using 250 samples. Have also tried 1000 samples and does not help. Can path tracing do large sizes? Anyone know why details are weak at hi res size?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know how you set up your project. Add images that might help us understand the issue. Consider uploading your file so that others can inspect it. Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and paste the  resulting link as part of your question.

Comment: Weird. Are you using the GPU? If so, try plain ol' CPU rendering.